# create post on vue js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

i want to create a post end send to api but i need to retrive userId to create my post.

( frontend : vuejs3 + axios backend : node + prisma + sql)

Test on postman is ok but i cannot retrive usedId in vue js.
can you help me please ?

```
import axios from "axios"
export default {
    name: 'PostCreate',
    data () {
        return {
            title: '',
            content: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async createPost(req) {
            const token = Authorization.split(' ')[1];

            // dechiffre le token a l'aide de la clé secrete et du token presant dans authorization
            const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, `${process.env.MY_TOKEN}`);
            console.log('decodedToken');
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/post', {

                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                },
                
                title: this.title,
                content: this.content,
                userId: decodedToken.userId
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define headers as the 3rd argument.

```js
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/post', {                
                title: this.title,
                content: this.content,
                userId: decodedToken.userId
            }, {
 headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') },
});
```

Comment: and how i can acces to my decodedToken.userid ?